# Modal popup on button click - Semantic UI

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

Hello I've recently been trying to get the modals working with Semantic-UI But I can't seem to get it to work how I want it to. I want to make it so that when a user clicks a specific menu on the sidebar a modal will pop up on the page where a user can input text. If anyone knows how to go about doing this please comment below! Thanks

```
<a class="item">
  <i class="money icon"></i>
  Free Coins
</a>
```

Thanks to anyone that can help!

Answer (score 3):

Change `<a class="item">` to `<a class="item" id="coins">`

jquery:

```
     <script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#coins').click(function(){
        $('#modalid').modal('show');    
     });
     });

     </script>
```

**Note:** #modalid is your modal div id.

Hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

$('#myModal').modal('attach events', 'a.item', 'show');

Comment: Code-only answers are rarely helpful (particularly on old questions where the OP has solved or given up on their problem) and are usually deleted. Please add a short explanation of your code and explain what it does and why someone should use it to solve this problem

Comment: it's not really my code. It's Semantic-ui call from their doc.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="ui container">
//model start
<div class="ui basic modal">
  <div class="ui icon header">
    <i class="archive icon"></i>
    Archive Old Messages
  </div>
 //content in model
  <div class="content">
    <p>Your inbox is getting full, would you like us to enable automatic archiving of old messages?</p>
  </div>
 //actions in the model(buttons)
  <div class="actions">
    <div class="ui red basic cancel inverted button">
      <i class="remove icon"></i>
      No
    </div>
    <div class="ui green ok inverted button">
      <i class="checkmark icon"></i>
      Yes
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
//model ends

//Button to click to pop up the model
<div class="ui button">
    <i class="remove"></i>
    delete
  </div>
</div>


//script
<script>
    $('.ui.button').click(function(){
        $('.ui.basic.modal').modal('show');

    });
</script>
```